# Application.DispatcherUnhandledException in VCL

Tags: c++, vcl, c++builder-6

In WPF(.net) I can use the following code to handle unexpected exceptions and exit my programm properly.

```
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e) {    
    this.DispatcherUnhandledException += App_DispatcherUnhandledException
}

private void App_DispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e) {
    // handle unhandled exception 
}
```

Is something like this availiable in VCL aswell? Or even in standard C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the `TApplication::OnException` event (also the `TApplicationEvents` wrapper component), eg:

```
__fastcall TMainForm::TMainForm(TComponent *Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
    Application->OnException = &AppException;
}

__fastcall TMainForm::~TMainForm()
{
    Application->OnException = NULL;
}

void __fastcall TMainForm::AppException(TObject *Sender, Exception *E)
{
    // handle unhandled exception 
}
```